# How to hide repeating part of the retrieved data values using PHP , MYSQL & HTML

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have obtained following table as a result of this MySQL statement

```
select entry.id as id, 
       entry.payorder, 
       entry.bank, 
       entry.PFMS_SCHEME, 
       entry.name, 
       entry.vendor, 
       tally_head.head, 
       ledgers.amount, 
       entry.po, 
       entry.Description, 
       bank_details.Name as name, 
       entry.sum as sum 
from entry  join bank_details on entry.name=bank_details.id  
            join ledgers on ledgers.id=entry.id  
            join tally_head on ledgers.ledger=tally_head.id 
group by tally_head.head
```

[result i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfZZs.jpg)

These are the mysql tables from which i am retrieving data
[entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVvK6.jpg)[bank table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMGXA.jpg)[ledger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2FA9.jpg)[tally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acqKP.jpg)

the final output i want
[the view i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdrB6.jpg)

The HTML and PHP Code I used`

```
                                 <table class="table">
                                   <thead>
                                      <tr>

                                        <th>Voucher No </th>
                                        <th>Payorder </th>
                                        <th>Bank </th>
                                        <th>PFMS_SCHEME </th>
                                        <th>Party Name </th>
                                        <th> For</th>
                                         <th>  Po/agmt/inv N.o </th>
                                         <th>Ledger</th>
                                         <th>Ledger Amount</th>

                                         <th>Description/ Narration</th>
                                        <th>sum</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>


     <?php
                     $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select   entry.id as cid,entry.payorder,entry.bank,entry.PFMS_SCHEME,entry.name,entry.vendor,tally_head.head,ledgers.amount,entry.po,entry.Description,bank_details.Name as name,entry.sum as sum from entry  join bank_details on entry.name=bank_details.id  join ledgers on ledgers.id=entry.id  join tally_head on ledgers.ledger=tally_head.id group by tally_head.head ");
$cnt=1;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))

?>

                                           <tr>

                                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['cid']);?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['payorder']);?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['bank']);?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['PFMS_SCHEME']);?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['name']);?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['vendor']);?></td>

                                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['po']);?></td>

                                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['head']);?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['amount']);?></td>

                                         <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['Description']);?></td>

                                            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['sum']);?></td>
                                        <td>






                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
<?php 
$cnt++;
?>


                                </tbody>
                               </table>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Basically you need a variable which can "remember" what was in the previous row, so you can compare it to the current row and decide whether to print certain fields, or not.

Comment: sir i cant understand what you are saying please give me some example

Comment: Let me try and explain it another way: In order to know whether you should display the fields from the "repeating" columns you must first know what was displayed in the previous line. e.g. in your case if the Voucher No of the line you're processing currently is the same as the Voucher No from the previous line, then you don't want to display it, so that it doesn't repeat. Therefore, each time you finish processing a line you must store the current Voucher No in another variable When the loop runs again to process the next line, you can compare the "old" Voucher No to the "new" one and decide.

Comment: Sir sorry to trouble you please explain me in term of code   I can’t understand what you are saying how to create a variable for it

Comment: "how to create a variable for it". Add `$previousRow = null;` just after `$cnt=1;` (but before the `while`. Then just before the end of the `while` loop, write `$previousRow = $row;`. That will store the current row's values inside a separate variable, so next time the loop runs it can be compared to the (new) current one.

Comment: P.S. in the code you've shown above, the `while` loop seems to be missing its `{` and `}` to start and end it. I assume you just forgot to add them in your example? It's not clear where the loop is supposed to finish, but I would guess it should logically end just after `$cnt++;`.

Comment: yes sir you are correct i removed '{' this before uploading.
but i did changes what you had suggested but the output was same sir

Comment: P.S. I'm trying to encourage you to learn for yourself by thinking about the problem and how to apply your knowledge to it. If you just want someone else to write the whole code for you, without any thought or effort on your part, you have come to the wrong place. Here's an idea: Consider how you would do this job on paper, if you were reading the SQL results from one sheet, and writing the new layout on another sheet. Break down your mental process into the tiny individual decisions and steps you would take. That should give you an algorithm. Next you can implement the algorithm using PHP.

Comment: Sir any how thanks for your suggestion.